# foreach echo array echos "Array" instead of values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, echo

This is my code:

```
$resultNew = $conn->query("SELECT getal FROM telling where tel = 'yes' group by getal order by getal");

while($rowNew = mysqli_fetch_array($resultNew))
{
    $rowsArrawNew[] = $rowNew;
}

foreach($rowsArrawNew as $value)
{
    echo "<TD>".$value. "</TD>";
}
```

The problem is: the output is: **Array Array Array Array** instead of **2 5 29 58** as I expected.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `$rowsArrawNew[] = $rowNew["getal"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can with extract function or association array ,
mysqli_fetch_array() return the association array ...

[extract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

```
$resultNew = $conn->query("SELECT getal FROM telling where tel = 'yes' group by getal order by getal");

while($rowNew = mysqli_fetch_array($resultNew))
{
    $rowsArrawNew[] = $rowNew;
}

foreach($rowsArrawNew as $value)
{

    extract ($value);
    echo "<TD>".$getal. "</TD>";
}
```

Or association array

```
$resultNew = $conn->query("SELECT getal FROM telling where tel = 'yes' group by getal order by getal");

while($rowNew = mysqli_fetch_array($resultNew))
{
    $rowsArrawNew[] = $rowNew;
}

foreach($rowsArrawNew as $value)
{
    echo "<TD>".$value['getal']. "</TD>";
}
```

Either working Dou you which one want do it

Answer (score 0):

As [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) returns an array of column values - even if there is only 1 value, when you add this in

```
$rowsArrawNew[] = $rowNew;
```

`$rowsArrawNew` will be an array of arrays.  To just get the 1 value your after, you can change either part to extract the value from the array...

```
$rowsArrawNew[] = $rowNew['getal'];
```

or

```
echo "<TD>".$value['getal']. "</TD>";
```

(But not both).